# Can a custom query return a model if all properties are not fetched in Spring JPA?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a model with lots of properties. For lists, I wanted to get only a few of those properties as most of them are shown only in detail views.

So I made up this query for my repository:

```
JpaRepository< Customer, Long >

@Query("SELECT id, name FROM Customer")
public List<Customer> findAllSummary();
```

It works - indeed an id and a name are returned, but not as a Customer object. This becomes a problem when I return the data to the JSON client: there are no property names, just the values for each row, while in the default queries also the names are returned, for example:

```
"id": 1
"name": "John"
// rest of the properties
```

Is there a way to make the custom query return model objects even though some properties would be null? Or is some other technique better for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a DTO with required fields and appropriate constructor, and return it from a query using constructor syntax:

```
@Query("SELECT new CustomerSummary(id, name) FROM Customer")
public List<CustomerSummary> findAllSummary();
```

Comment: Ok, but I guess I need another repository then? Because the customer repository is typed for Customer object?

Comment: I made another repository, but I still get the error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type. (crash at startup) Even if I add the full package name of CustomerSummary, which in the same package as Customer. Does CustomerSummary need some special annotation?

Comment: No, you don't need another repository nor special annotation. Just add it to your existing repository. And yes, you need full package name.

Comment: Apparently having another repository just messed it up - now it works - thanks!

Comment: The way spring setup its Specification, it appears that you can only modify the where clause for methods on the SimpleJpaRepository. Is there a nice way to extend that to support custom contructors so we can take advantage of these types of queries there too?